# Area of triangle on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

So I'm trying to compute the area of a triangle on a sphere of radius $R$. The triangle has a vertex at the north pole and its other two vertices are on the same colatitudinal line at $0$ and $\theta$. I'm not so much interested in the answer as to have my work checked and help me figure out where I went wrong.

So first, I worked out the "length" of a colatitude line. I'm using $\varphi$ as the colatitude:

$$2 \pi R sin(\varphi)$$

The "base" of the triangle should be scaled by $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$ so the base of a triangle as above with "height" $\varphi$ should be

$$\theta R sin(\varphi)$$

So the area of the triangle of height $\phi$ should be

$$\theta R \int_0^\phi sin(\varphi) d\varphi$$

Which I find to be

$$\theta R [1-cos(\phi)]$$

But I've clearly made a mistake somewhere because if we substitute in $\theta = 2\pi$ and $\phi=\pi$ we should get the whole surface of the sphere, but instead, I get $4\pi R$ which is off by a factor of $R$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I understand what the sides of the triangle are, but it is not clear to me what the base of the triangle is.  Do you really mean for the base of the triangle to be a “colatitudinal line”?  After all, this is not a geodesic on the sphere. Rather, it is an  arc of a small circle.  Ordinarily, when one speaks of a spheriical triangle, one means a triangle whose sides are segments of great circles.

Comment: Yes. I do mean for the base to be an arc of a small circle.

Comment: It appears you're calculating the area of the triangle by integrating the lengths of latitude lines...? That loses a factor of $R$: You need to multiply by the "width along the sphere" of the zonal sector between latitude $\varphi$ and latitude $\varphi + d\varphi$, which is $R\, d\varphi$, not $d\varphi$. (Alternatively, you could use Archimedes' theorem.)

Comment: I guess Archimedes’ Theorem is the one that says that a parallel slice through a sphere has area proportional to the thickness of the slice? That definitely gives an area of $\theta R^2(1-\cos\phi)$.

Comment: Is the base of the triangle a section of a great circle or a section of a parallel of latitude?

Comment: stretch The latter.

Answer (score 0):

My error is in specifying the integral. My goal was to add up the horizontal strips that make up the triangle. The height of those strips is proportional to the radius of the sphere. Specifically: $R d\varphi$. This is because $\varphi$ is an angle, not a vertical arc on the sphere. So the integral above should be

$$\theta R\int_0^\Phi sin(\varphi)Rd\varphi$$

When that extra $R$ is added, everything works out fine.